Guitar pro 7 on ubuntu 20.04
This question is pretty self-explanatory but how can I install GP7 on my Ubuntu?
Alternatively, I'll be glad to take any software that can open and play GP files and do it smoothly and  nicely. I've seen Tux Guitar and I didn't like it.
I am very new to Ubuntu and would appreciate the help!

Did you try installing Wine first?

You can install Windows in a virtualbox (Windows 11 trial is free to use indefinitely), and install GP7 there

Alternatively, you can use Musescore https://musescore.org/en/download. You can use tuxguitar to convert the files to GP5 or older format, and open that with Musescore.
